# Is it possible to change where a specific program stores its user local temp files externally?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to change where a specific program stores its temp files in appdata/local/temp. Since this program offers no built-in settings to do this, is it possible to do this externally (outside the program) with Windows such as with a custom shortcut?

The program is ACDSEE 20.

I don't wish to use the symlink method of creating a directory junction to the entire temp folder or editing the environment variable, since that has caused issues in the past with installers and Windows patches.

Comment: Please mention the name of that program.

Comment: @Biswa The program is ACDSEE 20. I've ammended the OP.